# how to increase the coverage of wordnet using wikipedia

Tags: knowledge-base

I want to increase the coverage of wordnet by increasing the synset count.

Is there a way in which I can proceed and increase sysnets. I am trying to work on Hindi wordnet with Princeton wordnet  as the  standard

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Open Multilingual Wordnet (http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/).

They used wiktionary (not wikipedia, because wikipedia lemmas are nouns only) to get translations and synsets. EDIT: In the extended version, there is also a Hindi wordnet with 3,593 synsets, see http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/summx.html

There is a non-open Hindi wordnet at https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2008L02.